# How to implement this problem in Common Lisp?

Tags: common-lisp

I'm a beginning programmer, who is very interested in Common Lisp, but doesn't know it at all. I would be very thankful to anyone, who can implement the following problem in Common Lisp, so I can see how Common Lisp handles basic things, like string processing, file I/O, etc.

Here is the problem:

**Example of input, read from "problem.in" file**:

```
3 5 
XHXSS 
XSHSX 
XXHSS
```

You are given **h** by **w** table of characters. The first number is the number of rows, second number is the number of columns.

For each column of characters you should do the following:

Begin looking through characters from top to bottom.

If 'X' is found, output the cost of the column (cost is zero by default) followed by space character and then go to the next column (skipping all other characters in the current column).

If 'S' is found, increase cost by 1.

If 'H' is found, increase cost by 3.

If there was no 'X' in the column, output 'N' followed by space character.

**Example of output, written to "problem.out" file**:

```
0 4 0 N 1
```

Here is my implementation in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{

    ifstream input;
    input.open("problem.in");

    ofstream output("problem.out");

    int h, w;
    input >> h >> w;

    string * str = new string[h];

    for(int i = 0; i < h; i++) input >> str[i];

    for(int i = 0; i < w; i++)
    {

        int cost = 0;
        bool found = false;

        for(int j = 0; j < h; j++)
        {
            char ch = str[j][i];
            if(ch == 'X') { found = true; break; }  
            else if(ch == 'S') cost += 1;
            else if(ch == 'H') cost += 3;
        }

        if(found) output << cost;
        else output << 'N';

        output << ' ';
    }

    input.close();
    output.close();

    return 0;
}
```

I would prefer to see this problem implemented as one function, something along these lines:

```
(defun main()

...

(with-open-file (input "problem.in" :direction :input)
(...))

...

(with-open-file (output "problem.out" :direction :output :if-exists :supersede)
(...))

...
)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
(defun solve-problem (in-file out-file)
  (labels ((solve (in out)
             (let ((h (read in))
                   (w (read in)))
               (compute-output out h w
                              (read-array in h w (make-array (list h w))))))
           (read-array (stream h w array)
             (loop for i below h do (read-line stream)
                   (loop for j below w
                         do (setf (aref array i j)
                                  (read-char stream))))
             array)
           (compute-output (stream h w array)
             (loop with x-p and cost for j below w do
               (setf x-p nil cost 0)
               (loop for i below h do
                 (case (aref array i j)
                   (#\X (setf x-p t) (return))
                   (#\S (incf cost))
                   (#\H (incf cost 3))))
               (format stream "~a " (if x-p cost #\N)))))
    (with-open-file (in in-file)
      (with-open-file (out out-file :direction :output :if-exists :supersede)
        (solve in out)))))

CL-USER 17 > (solve-problem "/tmp/test.data" "/tmp/result.text")
NIL

CL-USER 18 > (with-open-file (stream "/tmp/result.text") (read-line stream))
"0 4 0 N 1 "
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this. I have some problems with your code. You seem to get correct results, but I get the following results(on Windows 7): in Clozure Common Lisp 1.6 the result is 
0 3 0 4 N .

In Lispworks Personal 6.01 the result is: 
Error in process.
End of file while reading stream #<STREAM::EF-FILE-STREAM
C:\tmp\test.data>.

Comment: @Max: I get the correct result using Clozure CL on my Mac. Where do you get the LispWorks error? In the call to solve?

Comment: Try this version. One of the differences between Mac and Windows is the line end...

Comment: Now I don't have an error in Lispworks. Now I have the following: in Clozure the result is N 0 N 0 N . In Lispworks Personal 6.01 the result is 0 3 0 4 N . The encoding of "test.data" is ANSI and I think I do everything correctly. In Lispworks I insert your code and click "Compile buffer". In Clozure I copy your code into the text file and load it with (load "...")

Comment: I suspect there is something wrong with my machine, because I had similar problems while compiling Peter Norvig's code http://norvig.com/java-lisp.html (I also couldn't process the text files correctly and wasn't able to determine the reason). So, thank you once again for taking the time to respond.

Comment: @Max: Try this last version. If you want to debug it, you can insert a print statement in READ-ARRAY to output the read array.

Comment: @Max: you need to check the file and the READ-LINE function. LispWorks may be able to determine the line ending automatically. CCL may not. Make sure that READ-LINE is able to read lines including BOTH line end characters CR and LF (if the file is in Windows format).

Comment: Aha! Everything works now on both compilers. Thanks a million. :-)

Comment: I didn't save the first version of your code and I have only the new version, so I can't compare them on implementation level. But I somewhat vaguely understand that the problem was in the text file internal structure and how compiler handles it.

Answer (score 2):

You would *not* do this in a single function nowadays.  The 70's are over.

You would define a function `read-problem-set`, which returns a list of rows, each of which is a list of characters.  Then, you would define a function `transpose`, which transposes that to a list of columns.  The "meat" of the calculation would be done by a function `cost`, which reads in a column and returns its cost.  Finally, you can write a function `output-column-costs`, which writes a list to the specified file in the required format.  Connect all the pieces in a function `solve-problem`:

```
(defun solve-problem (in-file out-file)
  (output-column-costs out-file
                       (mapcar #'cost
                               (transpose (read-problem-set in-file)))))
```

Comment: I know that it can be implemented with many functions, but I consciously chose one function. I just wanted to see how it would look. But anyway, any kind of complete working implementation would be nice. :-)